# Angular animations: the style() function doesn't change property unless it's in camel case

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have a *transition* between *states*. The *transition* receives an array and the third item in the array is the `style` function that should apply `'background-color' : 'red'`.
For some reason Angular doesn't apply the style unless I declare it with camel case: `backgroundColor: 'red'`.

Is this a bug or it's expected behavior?

[image: background-color property declared with quotes]
[image: background-color property declared with camel case]

Here's the project on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vhkked?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Here's the code snippet of declared animations:

```
animations: [
    trigger('numberEnteredState', [
      state(
        'unselected',
        style({
          border: '1px solid black',
          padding: '5px',
        })
      ),
      state(
        'selected',
        style({
          border: '2px solid blue',
          padding: '4px',
          'background-color': 'lightblue',
        })
      ),
      transition('unselected => selected', [
        style({
          border: '2px solid black',
          padding: '4px',
        }),
        animate('3000ms'),
        style({
          'background-color': 'red',
        }),
        animate('3000ms'),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
})
```

The same `style()` function with css property declared within quotation marks works just fine inside the animation state:

```
      state(
        'selected',
        style({
          border: '2px solid blue',
          padding: '4px',
          'background-color': 'lightblue',
        })
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Naveen stated - [Documentation:](https://angular.io/guide/animations#animation-state-and-styles)

> Use the style() function to define a set of styles to associate with a given state name. You must use camelCase for style attributes that contain dashes, such as backgroundColor or wrap them in quotes, such as 'background-color'

Updated:

However, when you define a `background-color` property in the initial state it seems to recognize that in the transition -> styles. This is very inconsistent behavior. This does seem like a bug.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e4xvwg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
trigger('numberEnteredState', [
      state(
        'unselected',
        style({
          border: '1px solid black',
          padding: '5px',
          'background-color': 'white',
        })
      ),
      state(
        'selected',
        style({
          border: '2px solid blue',
          padding: '4px',
          'background-color': 'lightblue',
        })
      ),
      transition('unselected => selected', [
        style({
          border: '2px solid green',
          padding: '4px',
        }),
        animate('3000ms'),
        style({
          'background-color': 'red',
        }),
        state(
          'selected',
          style({
            border: '2px solid blue',
            padding: '4px',
            backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
          })
        ),
        animate('3000ms'),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/animations#animation-state-and-styles): Use the `style()` function to define a set of styles to associate with a given state name. You must use *camelCase* for style attributes that contain dashes, such as `backgroundColor` or wrap them in quotes, such as `'background-color'`.

Comment: yes. does seem like a bug.